# What does the "BoundNames of formals" mean in ES6 specification

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm reading 9.2.12 in ES6 specification, there is "Let parameterNames be the BoundNames of formals" at stap 7.

But what does the "BoundNames of formals" mean? I know formals is the FormalParameters list.

Do you have some examples? Or can you explain that more detailedly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`formals` is a variable, introduced on step 6:

> 6. Let formals be the value of the [[FormalParameters]] internal slot of func.

`BoundNames` is a procedure, described (among others) in [14.1.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions-static-semantics-boundnames) which returns a list `StringValues` of formals' identifiers. In plain terms, step 7 extracts a list of parameter names from the `[[FormalParameters]]` property.

Comment: Thanks. You mean If the code is: 1.function foo(x, y) {} 2.function foo(x, ...y) {} 3.function (){x, y} {} so, the parameterNames should be 1.['a', 'b'] 2.['a', 'b'] 3.['default'] If I'm right,can you supplement some other situations that ignored by me    @georg

Comment: No, "default" is only used for function names, not parameters. So for all three it will be `[x, y]`.

Comment: Thanks.I get your idea.

By the way, is there any other situation that ignored by me?

@georg